# How to reload another view controller's tableview data

Tags: iphone, delegates, notifications, viewcontroller

Right now, in FirstviewController, I got a button, when i clicked it, I get the value back using delegate. Right now, I want to send this value to SecondViewcontroller and reload it's tableview data. How to do that? How about use nsnotificationcenter, but i have tried, it's not working. I post the notification in the delegate that implemented in Firstviewcontroller. the code like this:

```
FirstviewController.m

// delegate that get selected cat
- (void)didSelectSubCat:(SubCat *)cat;
{
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"DidSelectCat" object:self userInfo:@{@"catId": cat.catId}];
}

SecondViewcontroller.m

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(selectedCat:) name:@"DidSelectCat" object:nil];
}

- (void)selectedCat:(NSNotification *)notif
{
    NSLog(@"userinfo: %@", [notif userInfo]);
}
```

Comment: Hey using protocol concept .....

Answer (score 0):

In SecondViewCOntroller create protocol with a methode

```
     @protocol TeamListViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

       -(void)SecondViewController:(SecondViewController*)teamListViewController data:(NSString*)data

        @end
```

declare delegate

```
      @property(nonatomic,assign) id<TeamListViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
```

In firstViewcontroller follow that protocol and implement that method and inside that method refresh table.
I hope this will help.

Comment: But I am not getting data from SecondViewController. I am to send the data to SecondViewController, and refresh SecondViewController's tableview data.